# "..... come 2025." What's the usage of "come" here?

Tags: word-usage

There is a conversation from a parent to the baby about its passport photograph,"We'll get you a new one come 2025".

I can sense that he means they will update their baby's passport photo at around 2025. Just wondering what's the usage of "come" here? Is it quite common in oral English when someone needs to express "close to, near to".

Thank you so much!

Comment: It _doesn't_ mean 'near to' - as DjinTonic says, it means 'when 2025 comes'.

Comment: Whar @KateBunting said. In "literary / linguistic" terms, it's ["stylistic inversion".](https://www.thoughtco.com/inversion-grammar-term-1691193#:~:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20inversion%20is,(subject%2Dverb%20inversion).&text=Also%20called%20stylistic%20inversion%20and,verb%20in%20the%20verb%20phrase.)

Answer (score 2):

**come** (v.)

> **To come to pass**: take place —used in the subjunctive with inverted
> subject and verb to express the particular time or occasion
>
> *Come spring the days will be longer.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come)

> Preceding a future date, time, or event. When or by the time the
> specified date or event arrives or takes place; **at or by the specified
> time**.
>
> *We'll be married eighteen years come next Tuesday.* OED

---

> ... and we would be disposing of Doctor Millions' cow herd,
> consequently there would be only enough work for Albert and Stretch
> **come next winter**. [Baxter Keith; *The Judas Kiss*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Judas_Kiss/sZOTsbqveyoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22come%20next%20winter%22&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover)

Often used with expressions: *come what may, come rain or shine*, etc.

> **Come hell or high water**—whatever the obstacles. E.g.,  **Come hell or high water**, I am determined to succeed. I am anxious to succeed.
> [Rebecca Vorsah; *General Knowledge of English Literature*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/General_Knowledge_of_English_Literature/-e1QAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22come%20hell%20or%20highwater%22&pg=PT53&printsec=frontcover)

> ...Daniel's vision shows that regardless of a person's power, might or
> control in this world, in the end, **come judgement day**, people will
> find out who really is in control and will receive their just rewards.
> [Brian Curtis; *Bits and Pieces 2018*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bits_and_Pieces_2018/_cONDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22come%20judgement%20day%22&pg=PA215&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Djin